# Settings for ESLINT to ignore warnings like "extra semicolon"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, atom-editor, eslint

I'm using the Atom Code Editor for a VueJS Project with ESLINT (feross). By trying to quickly prototype a layout I get these errors.

> Missing space before opening brace
>    Strings must use singlequote
>   Extra semicolon

During the prototype phase I would like ESLINT/ATOM to disable/ignore these errors and render the site anyways.
How to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could temporarily turn off eslint. In my setup, inspecting `build/webpack.base.conf.js` shows the following snippet:

```
  module: {
    rules: [
      ...(config.dev.useEslint ? [createLintingRule()] : []),
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
```

The linting rule will enable eslint. Lets avoid that and set `config.dev.useEslint` to `false`. Go to `config/index.js` and alter the following snippet:

```
// Use Eslint Loader?
// If true, your code will be linted during bundling and
// linting errors and warnings will be shown in the console.
useEslint: false,
```

Answer (score 4):

In your `.eslintrc` file, do the following:

```
  "rules": {
    "space-before-blocks": "off",
    "quotes": "off",
    "no-extra-semi": "off"
  }
```

This will turn off the above rules. I would suggest instead of turning it off let it throw warning, so in future you remember to fix these issues.

ESLint has an awesome documentation: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/